# Concatenating stream in it's own forEach loop

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Example 1:

```
 public TailCall<TestClass> useOfStream(Stream<Test> streamL) {
        ArrayList<Test> testList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Stream<Test> streamL2 = testList2.stream();

        streamL.forEach(test -> {
            for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
                if (/*insert if statement*/) {
                    Test test2 = new Test();
                    Stream<Test> streamT = stream.of(test2);
                    **streamL2.concat(streamL2, streamT);**
                } else {
                    //do something with TestClass
                }
            }
        });
        if (streamL2.findAny().isPresent()) {
            return call(() -> useOfStream(streamL2));
        } else {
            return TailCalls.done(TestClass);
        }
    }
```

So, for a certain element in `streamL` I can possibly make up to 13 same-class elements. These newly made elements (that I've added to `streamL2`) should be iterated over the same way `streamL` was iterated over. Is there a possibility of adding those new elements to `streamL`?
Doing:

```
    streamL.forEach(test -> {
        for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            if (/*insert if statement*/) {
                Test test2 = new Test();
                Stream<Test> streamT = stream.of(test2);
                **streamL.concat(streamL, streamT);**
            } else {
                //do something with TestClass
            }
        }
    });
```

If it's even possible to concat a stream within it's own for-Each loop, would the forEach loop also go through those newly added elements? That would eliminate my need of a recursive method.
Another question is, will an object made within a stream (for ex. `Test test2 = new Test();` in the forEach loop of streamL) be processed lazily by the program? With other words, would this object take any place in the memory heap? (but this question is not that important, primarily my first question)

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking but I'd suggest you look into `Stream.flatMap(...)`.

Comment: Is the second block of code possible to do? That's what I'm asking... And if yes, does that mean that the initial forEach loop of streamL continues until the end of the original streamL when the forEach-loop was called or if  it continues until the real end of the stream (having looped through the newly added elements as well).

Comment: I don't see any difference between the "second" code block and the center part of the first one. As I said I'm not sure I understand what you're after but using `flatMap()` should get you there (maybe in combination with `IntStream`).

Comment: I could put the existing streamL or streamL2 and the newly added element (test2) together in a same stream with flatmap instead of concat, but I don't really know if this would help me with anything regarding my question.

Comment: In the first block, I'm making a streamL2 before the forEach of streamL and adding all newly made elements to streamL2, then at the end of forEach i'm checking if streamL2 is empty, if not I give this stream back to the useOfStream-method. In the second block, I'm not making any streamL2 but trying to add new elements to the streamL which I'm forEach-looping through

Comment: Well, I can't tell you either because the question is not clear enough for me to understand what you're trying to achieve. Rephrasing or adding examples might help.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't really clear. But I guess I don't know how to make it clearer. I could just change the name of streamL and streamL2 to make it clearer? Just try to recheck the code, and see the difference in  **streamL2.concat(streamL2, streamT);** and  **streamL.concat(streamL, streamT);**.

Comment: seeing the below answer I get what you meant by flatmap. If that's what you meant. :)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant and seeing that you've accepted the answer I assume that's what you wanted :)

Comment: I can't upvote comments yet but I would've with yours ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace first `forEach`  with `flatMap` and use `Stream.builder()` to create a sub stream with both additional elements and reused `t` element:

```java
Stream.of("A1", "A2").flatMap(t -> {
    Stream.Builder<String> subStream = Stream.builder();
    subStream.add(t);
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        subStream.add("B" + i);
    }
    return subStream.build();
}).forEach(System.out::print);
```

prints

```
A1B1B2A2B1B2
```

Comment: Or `.flatMap(t -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(t), IntStream.range(1, 3).mapToObj(i -> "B"+i)))`

Comment: Great thanks, so there is no way of avoiding my recursive method. If I want to iterate over the new elements and do the same thing I have to recall my method with the new flatmapped stream as parameter. The return subStream.build() is only instantiated when all elements of Stream.of("A1", "A2") have been looped through by the flatMap()-method?